# Caching Dynamic data that isn't really dynamic in an IIS7 environment

Tags: caching, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

Okay, so I have an old ASP Classic website.  I've determined I can reduce a huge number of DB calls by caching the data daily.  Our site data is read only, and changes very slowly.  I think based on our site usage, I would be able to cache pages by query string for every visit each day, without a hit to our server.

My first thought was to use Output Caching, but the problem I discovered right away was that it wasn't until the third page request was generated that I gained any performance.  I verified this using SQL profiler,  but I'm not sure why.

My second thought was to add this ObjPageCache include file from https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131054/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032002-1.shtml After some research I discovered that this could cause more issues than it may solve http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316451

I'm hoping someone on here will tell me that since 2002 the issue with Sending ServerXMLHTTP or WinHTTP Requests to the Same Server has been resolved with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your data is maintained you could choose from a number of ways to cache it.

If your data is changed and saved in one single place you could choose to generate an html-file which you save to the serverdisk and refer to in your linking. This will require write access for the process running your site though (e.g. NETWORK SERVICE). This will produce fast pages as the server serves these pages without any scriptingengine getting involved.

Another option is reading the data into an DomDocument which you store in the Application object and refer to on the page that needs it (hence saving the roundtrip to the database). You could keep two timestamps together with the cached data (one for the cachingtime and one for the time of change of data in the database). Timestamps will allow for fast check for staleness of the cached data: cached timestamp <> database timestamp => refresh data; otherwise use cached data. One thing to note about this approach is that Application does not accept objects other than multithreaded object so you will have to use the MSXML2.FreeThreadedDomDocument.6.0

Personally I prefer the last one as it allows for a more dynamic usage and I don't have to worry about write access permissions for the process running my site (which would probably pose security risks anyways).